# React setTimeout hooks onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, react-hooks, state

It is giving an error Cannot read property 'handleCheck' of undefined when I click on next button. Can anyone please help?Thanks in advance

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { check: false };
  handleCheck = () => {
    console.log("hello");
    this.setState({ check: !this.state.check });
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.handleCheck();
    }, 10000);
  }
  timer() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.handleCheck();
    }, 10000);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>hello</p>
        {this.state.check ? (
          <button onClick={this.timer}>Next</button>
        ) : (
          <div>button not showing </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: @Red Baron Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make it an arrow function:

```
  timer = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.handleCheck();
    }, 1000);
  }
```

so it's bound to the parent scope

Comment: Yes it did!Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The `timer` should also be an arrow function to refer to the correct `this`:

```
timer = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.handleCheck();
    }, 10000);
  }
```

the other way to fix this would be to bind `this` to `timer`.

And since the new state depends on the old state, the `handleCheck` function should be like this:

```
handleCheck = () => {
    console.log("hello");
    this.setState(prevState => ({ check: !prevState.check }));
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a binding issue of `timer` function :

```
  timer = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.handleCheck();
    }, 10000);
  }
```

OR change `onClick` :

```
onClick={this.timer.bind(this)}
```

**Solution :**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { check: false };
  handleCheck = () => {
    console.log("hello");
    this.setState({ check: !this.state.check });
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.handleCheck();
    }, 10000);
  }
  timer = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.handleCheck();
    }, 10000);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>hello</p>
        {this.state.check ? (
          <button onClick={this.timer}>Next</button>
        ) : (
          <div>button not showing </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react-root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind this to the timer function.

```
<button onClick={this.timer.bind(this)}>Next</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the arrow function as other users said, or as alternative you can manually bind this to the function:

```
// in the button
<button onClick={this.timer.bind(this)}>Next</button>
// or in the constructor
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.timer = this.timer.bind(this)
}
<button onClick={this.timer)}>Next</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

hi as previous people said you need to bind (this) one of the way is to do it like this

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state =  { check: false };

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleCheck = this.handleCheck.bind(this);
  }
```

this is happens because when you enter a function the class this can't be reach
bind solve this in regular function
when you go with arrow function this scope don't use there on this scope instead  they inherit the one from the parent scope
like this:
instead of:

```
  timer() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.handleCheck();
    }, 10000);
  }
```

do this:

```
  timer = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.handleCheck();
    }, 10000);
  }
```