# React Link To button timeout

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, settimeout

I have a simple button that when I click him he redirect me to another page in the website
now using react router ( `<Link to=''>`). now what's I want is when I click the button he wait 3 seconds and then redirect me
how can I accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: did you try using `setTimeout` function?

Comment: I think about that but I dont exactly know how to initialize it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62428273/react-settimeout-hooks-onclick this might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom link component that takes an additional delay.

Example:

Use a click handler to prevent the default link action so you can "inject" your delayed navigation. Use a React ref to store a reference to the timer and a mounting `useEffect` hook to clear any running timers in the case the component is unmounted prior to expiration. Use the `useNavigate` hook to then imperatively navigate with all the appropriate parameters.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const DelayedLink = ({ delay, replace, state, to, ...props }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const timerRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => () => clearTimeout(timerRef.current), []);

  const clickHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    timerRef.current = setTimeout(navigate, delay, to, { replace, state });
  };

  return <Link to={to} {...props} onClick={clickHandler} />;
};
```

Usage:

```
<DelayedLink delay={3000} to="/test">
  Test
</DelayedLink>
<DelayedLink delay={3000} to="/test" state="foobar">
  Test w/state
</DelayedLink>
<DelayedLink to="/test">Test w/o delay</DelayedLink>
```

[image: Edit react-link-to-button-timeout]

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout). If you wrap setTimeout around your button's onClick method then you will be able to introduce a delay.

For example, here's a button which when you click it it waits 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds) before opening Stack Overflow in another tab:

```
<button
  onClick={() => setTimeout(() => window.open("https://stackoverflow.com/"), 3000)}
>
  Click me!
</button>
```

Comment: Thats exactly whats I meant for , but there is a way with Link To from react-router-dom or I must use window.open() ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<button
  onClick={() => setTimeout(() => window.open("url", '_blank'), 3000)}
>
  I will run after 3 seconds
</button>
```

This will work!

or try with the **useNavigate** in **react-router-dom**